# Accumulated value -java - simple question

Tags: java, variables, store

one simple question. I need to sum a value, when a condition is verified, so i have this code

```
private int sum;
private int sum1;
private int sum2;
private int sum3;

public int pontuationOfplayers() {
    if (winner() == 0) {
        return sum += 20;
    }
    else if (winner()==1) {
        return sum1 += 20;
    }
    else if (winner() ==2) {
        return sum2 += 20;
}
    else
        return sum3 += 20;
    }
```

the problem that i have is when the method is called it always start again with 0, so the result must be like, 20, 40, 60, but because of new initialization is always 20.

how can i solve that? like store the value of the variable

thanks!

script:edit

Comment: `return sum += value0 += 20;` (and the variation in the `else`) is clever as hell. Note that I'm a Python programmer, we don't consider "clever" a compliment ;) Read: Better write it less tricky and more understandably.

Comment: If you're not familiar scope (important concept) take a look at these links: http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/declarations/scope.html http://www.techrepublic.com/article/intro-to-oop-java-scope-rules/5035301

Comment: I don't follow the edits - they won't be reset to 0 now, so can you clarify where the problem lies? On a more general note it looks like you want to have four instances of one class (probably in array) and call the method on the array element which matches the winner number.

Comment: yes you are correct, but the question is if i need the four variables to four players, but i think so

Comment: Yes you need four variables, but you might want to consider using [arrays](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for this, since you can access them by number rather than a big block if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make sum a [class member](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), e.g.:

```
private int sum = 0;

public int pontuationOfplayers() {
    if (winner() == 0) {
        System.out.println("aqui");
        int value0 = 0;
        return sum += value0+=20;
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("aquiii");
        int value3 = 0;
        return sum += value3+=20;
    }
}
```

---

Based on your update I would suggest doing:

```
private int sum[] = new int[4];

public int pontuationOfplayers() {
    // (assuming winner() returns 3 for the final case)
    return sum[winner()] += 20;
}
```

Comment: post edited: it is possible to simplify it or do differently?

Comment: Since you return the sum you could also pass the existing sum in to the function when you call it, but from what I've seen here this really looks like an example where you want the sum to be a member.

Comment: @Fei - I've updated the answer to show how it could be simplified now too.

Answer (score 1):

`sum` should be a member of the class and thus defined

```
private int sum = 0;
```

within the class(but outside the methods). It is then preserved within the *instance* of the class, exists for the lifetime of that instance and can be modified by the methods within the class.

What you currently have defined exists only for the lifetime of the method invocation, and will go out of scope as soon as you exit that method.

Comment: Doh! Miles away. Corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

make sum an instance variable of your class. currently it is a local variable and hence it is initiatilized per method call.

Answer (score 1):

The sum value will need to be created and stored outside this method if it is called several times and you want to maintain the sum.  Either store it in a class variable or a local variable in the method that is calling the pontuationOfplayers() method.

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers solve your problem, they don't address what caused it: you are just starting to learn to program.

Read beginner tutorials on Java, Java classes and Java OOP (object-oriented programming). For example, you may start with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168919/java-tutorials-for-beginning-programmer

**Happy coding!**

Comment: i am Portuguese too :) thanks for reply. It is possible to simplify the code above? i edited my code

Comment: use a switch instead of chaining ifs. Link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html - also, ``sum+=20; return sum;`` is easier to read and avoids potential mistakes!